# How to collect a record by a parameter python

Tags: python, flask

Python source :

```
@app.route('/pret/<int:idPret>', methods=['GET'])
def descrire_un_pret(idPret):

    j = 0

    for j in prets:
        if prets[j]['id'] == idPret:
            reponse = make_response(json.dumps(prets[j],200))
            reponse.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
            return reponse
```

I would like to retrieve a record in the `prets` list by the `idPret` parameter. Nevertheless I get an error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j` is not a number. `j` is one element in the `prets` list. Python loops are foreach loops. `if j['id'] == idPret:` would work:

```
for j in prets:
    if j['id'] == idPret:
        reponse = make_response(json.dumps(j, 200))
        reponse.headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
        return reponse
```

I'd use a different name here, and use the [`flask.json.jsonify()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.json.jsonify) to create the response:

```
from flask import jsonify

for pret in prets:
    if pret['id'] == idPret:
        return jsonify(pret)
```

`jsonify()` takes care of converting to JSON and creating the response object with the right headers for you.

Comment: Thank's for that answer and explanation. Effectively the result is good.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking Python's for behavior for Javascript's. When you do 
`for j in prets:` in Python, the contents of `j` are already the elements in `pretz`, not an index number.